# Pasar argumento null || string con valor default en función PHP

Tags: php, php7

Tengo un archivo que recibe los parametros, si son un string vacio, les asigna el valor null y llama a la función:

```
@$column = htmlspecialchars($_GET['column']);
$column = $column ? $column : null;
$Accesos->get($column);
```

Tengo una función:

```
public function get(?string $column = 'id') {}
```

La idea es que acepte únicamente strings y valores nulos (en este caso, se le asignaría por default: 'id'). El problema, está en que no le asigna el valor por default, simplemente la pasa como null.

El ? permite que se ingresen valores NULL, y el string que solamente acepten strings... Necesito que si se ingresa un valor null, se le asigne el valor por default del parametro.

Gracias!

Comment: en cualquier otro lenguaje, te diria que es logico, pq si tu funcion acepta nulos en un valor que tiene algo por defecto (lo cual es muy raro), cuando la llames sin nada, la estas llamando con null, y entonces, si le estas pasando un valor valido. Usualmente poner algo por defecto se usa cuando null no es un valor aceptable. Como sabrias si paso null en serio, o no quiso pasar ningun valor, si en las llamadas null es que no paso ningun valor?

Comment: para mi, que lo que querias es que no acepte valores nulos, asi si viene un null, cambia al valor por defecto...

Comment: Es una función que se utiliza para hacer consultas SQL, por lo que siempre debe haber un valor por default.

Comment: y entonces porque acepta nulos? leiste mi explicacion?

Comment: El argumento solamente acepta strings, pero en caso de que se envíe un nulo, se le asigna el valor por default. Si no acepto nulos, me devuelve un error de tipo incorrecto (que solamente acepta strings, y que se envió un null)

Comment: y como la estas llamando?

Comment: @$column        = htmlspecialchars($_GET['column']);  $column = $column ? $column : null; $Accesos->get($column);

Comment: Obtiene los parametros a través de $_GET, y si la variable está vacia (PHP lo procesa siempre como string), se le asigna el valor null, posteriormente se los envía a la función.

Comment: Podrias poner todo en la pregunta? igual, [mira esta respuesta en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9166950/73749). PHP para variar hace lo que quiere... no toma tu null como null, si no que parece que lo toma como valor.. que error te dice en la llamada?

Comment: y mira [aca el ejemplo 3](http://php.net/manual/es/functions.arguments.php)

Comment: Ahí subi la actualización, si no especifico el tipo, funciona (ej: $column = 'id'), el tema es que solo quiero que pasen strings, y si es null, se le asigne el valor 'id'

Comment: segun el manual: NULL siempre es convertido a un string vacío.  o sea.. tu idea es buena, pero hay que aplicarla de otra manera...

Comment: En que parte lo dice? http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.null.php acá dice que basicamente, es la ausencia de un valor, y null es del tipo null. Gracias

Comment: ¿Y por qué no lo haces en el ternario directamente: `$column = $column ? $column : 'id';` ? ... Aunque tu planteamiento es confuso. Dices que quieres que acepte solamente strings o `null`, ¿qué valor debería asumir en caso de no ser string ni null?

Comment: @A.Cedano No se aceptan valores que no sean ni string ni null. En caso de ser null estaría bueno que se hiciera uso del valor por default. Aunque finalmente me parece que voy a tener que usar ternarios... La idea es ahorrar la mayor cantidad de código posible

Comment: Todavía no alcanzo a entender del todo tu problema. A ver si logro hacerte las preguntas aclaratorias. El valor `$colum` que pasas a la función `get` ¿es sólo para usarlo en esa función, y cuando sea nulo debe adquirir el valor `id`?  Si es así, olvídate del ternario, con que signes tu función así: `function get($column='id') {  //... }` sería suficiente. Ahora bien, si el dato no es sólo para pasarlo como parámetro a la función, debes construirlo mediante el ternario haciendo simplemente esto: `$column = $column ? $column : 'id';`

Comment: @A.Cedano la idea es que pase un parametro NULL o STRING, si es nulo, debe tomar el valor 'id'